# Python code does not work with RasterCalculator after exported from ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, error-000732

I have a model authored in ModelBuilder that uses "RasterCalculator" to process input raster datasets.

```
 arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("OutRas = Con(\"%STATIC_forestland%\"  ==  0, -255, Con(\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" >= 115, -255, Con((\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" >100) & (\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" < 115), 100, Con(\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" <= -15, -255, Con((\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" < 0) & (\"%mapvictoria20121210%\" > -15), 0, \"%mapvictoria20121210%\")))))", mapvic1)
```

It works well as a model. However, when exported to a Python script and saved in the same Toolbox, the script does not work.

The error message is as below

```
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset %mapvictoria20121210% does not exist or is not supported
```

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).

I am sure the input raster are there. Can anyone give some help? Is it to do with raster naming issues?

Comment: In my experience the Export to Python script-function is not fail safe, and usually only provides a not too bad starting point for a script. I can't remember any non-trivial model that I converted to a script which worked right away. 
Post your full script and you might get some hints on what is wrong :)

Comment: The percent symbols appear to be hardcoded, which I assume is from using them as variables in model builder.

Comment: The percent symbols are hardcoded from conversion from Model Builder to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might help you some:

```
stat = "STATIC_forestland"    
vict = "mapvictoria20121210"   
con = 'OutRas = Con("{0}" == 0, -255, Con("{1}" >= 115, -255, 
       Con(("{1}" > 100) & ("{1}" < 115), 100, Con("{1}" <= -15, -255, 
       Con(("{1}" < 0) & ("{1}" > -15), 0, "{1}")))))'.format(stat, vict)

arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(con, mapvic1)
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [ArcGIS help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000z7000000.htm):

> The Raster Calculator tool is intended for use in the ArcGIS Desktop application only as a GP tool dialog box or in ModelBuilder. It is not intended for use in scripting and is not available in the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module.

You need to use the [Spatial Analyst module](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00p600000002000000) map algebra syntax instead.