# Subtracting two ascii files using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have many files with name format yyyymmddhhmm_tprate.asc 201508010600_tprate.asc , 201508011200_tprate , 201508011800_tprate, 201508020000_tprate and so on ..........

I want to subtract 201508011200_tprate - 201508010600_tprate, 201508011800_tprate-201508011200_tprate and so on and want to save these files with a new name.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could try to convert your ascii files to rasters:

```
 import arcpy,os,re
 from arcpy import env
 from arcpy.sa import *
 arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

 arcpy.env.workspace = (r"<where ascii files are">)
 out_dir = (r"<Where you want them to go>")


  asciilist = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","ASCII")
  count = 1
  for ascii in asciilist:
     outRaster = arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(ascii, "", "INTEGER")
     outname = os.path.join(out_dir, str(ascii)) # Create the full out path
     outRaster.save(outname)
```

2) You can try a raster calculator workaround using the answer to [Raster Calculator Workaround in Arcpy for Suitabiliy Analysis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94392/raster-calculator-workaround-in-arcpy-for-suitabiliy-analysis)